# Prevent pandoc restarting footnote and odd footnote inside table

Tags: footnotes, chapters

In my `pandoc` document, I'm using `\documentclass[…]{scrbook}` and each chapter restarts the footnote number. Is there any way to prevent this?

Here is my generated `LaTeX` header:

```latex
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  open=right,
  twoside=false,
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  clearpage=empty]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % this also loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else
  % xetex/luatex font selection
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=25mm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,width=150mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\passthrough}[1]{#1}
\lstset{defaultdialect=[5.3]Lua}
\lstset{defaultdialect=[x86masm]Assembler}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\csllabelwidth}
\setlength{\csllabelwidth}{3em}
\newlength{\cslentryspacingunit} % times entry-spacing
\setlength{\cslentryspacingunit}{\parskip}
\newenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-ident, #2 entry spacing
 {% don't indent paragraphs
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1
  \let\oldpar\par
  \def\par{\hangindent=\cslhangindent\oldpar}
  \fi
  % set entry spacing
  \setlength{\parskip}{#2\cslentryspacingunit}
 }%
 {}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\CSLBlock}[1]{#1\hfill\break}
\newcommand{\CSLLeftMargin}[1]{\parbox[t]{\csllabelwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CSLRightInline}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth - \csllabelwidth}{#1}\break}
\newcommand{\CSLIndent}[1]{\hspace{\cslhangindent}#1}
\ifLuaTeX
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\else
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\fi
\babelprovide[main,import]{ngerman}
% get rid of language-specific shorthands (see #6817):
\let\LanguageShortHands\languageshorthands
\def\languageshorthands#1{}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=1000
```